# How to add restriction to Users in Odoo

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

I have **boolean** validation field in a module called **billing_notice**. I only want some users to modify this field.

Let's say, I have user1 user2 and user3

I only want user1 to have the power to modify this field. How can I do this restriction with python code or xml code? If you can provide some example I would love it.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do you want to restrict users to modify it or also want to make it invisible? If both, it is simple solution.

Comment: Hello Bhabesh! I only want users to modify. Everybody can see this field, but only some user with the priviledge can modify it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply specify the rules inside ir.model.access.csv
For reference you can go to [Odoo Technical Training](https://github.com/odoo/technical-training-solutions) repo and search for the file mentioned above.
There you will notice that some groups will have all access (notice the trailing 1,1,1,1 at the end of the row ) and some will have less ( 1,0,1,1 or 1,0,1,1) for example.